# detect nail in hand using opencv in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the OpenCv Library for the object detection.
I downloaded the given example of face detection. In this example they are using `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`.

I have to detect Nail in hand. Please suggest me how can I do it?
I also saw this-
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/detection_of_planar_objects/detection_of_planar_objects.html#detectionofplanarobjects

Please suggest me how I detect nail in hand.

Comment: Do you mean a literal nail jabbed into a human hand...?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect nail in hand's fingre only

Comment: @kitschmaster :when you say amazing question what do you mean, I am not understanding please explain.

Comment: Currently after a long googling i found the haarcascade_hand.xml,But when i am using this xml then getting some parsing error,Please suggest me if anyone knows,thanks to all who are commenting and voting on this question.

Comment: @ArunSharma ii guess You would have to create a haarcascade xml file for a nail first. for that You need to learn how to train haarcascades  like this http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Comment: Any success? I am looking for the same @San007

Comment: @San007 Any progress? I'm also looking for the same.